# Why are my reflections different in the viewport vs a full render when using Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm working on a character here. I can't manage to understand why I get the eye reflections when I'm in render mode viewport and why those same reflections disappear when I render the image. Of course I checked that the eye cornea is active in render. Screen space reflection is activated and I didn't have this issue few days back.
Is there anyone here to help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Is **everything** visible in viewport=render. There may still be some hidden objects obstructing the light source which only show up in render?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but no, no hidden objects. And the light that reflect is also lighting the face. If I delete it, the front part of the face is black. So the light is effective but there is no reflection in the cornea when rendered.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. I had activated subsurface direct in render passes settings.

Comment: Funny solution, please add that as answer for future visitors having the same issue. Really interested how a render pass effects the lighting.

Answer (score 0):

I hid a mesh in viewport but not hide in render, so only in view port light was visible.

[image]